# Iterative BLAST to find homologous genes

Tags: python, matrix, bioinformatics, blast

I'm new to programming I have been working on a bioinformatics problem for the past couple of weeks and progress has been extremely limited.

I have a large FASTA file with numerous genomes, I wish to run an all-vs-all BLAST search which will identify homologs/orthologs (which will be identified by having >=95% sequence similarity across their length using -outfmt 6) within my file and print those and non-homologous/orthologous genes to an organism-vs-gene presence/absence matrix (“1” = present, “0” = absent. I have been advised that an interative all-vs-all BLAST which updates all homologies/orthologies to a file then removes these from the database and repeats the procedure until no more relevant BLAST searches can be performed may be a way to approach this, but despite my efforts I cannot figure out how to even do this. I would prefer to do this in Python and or Unix/Linux where possible.

Can anybody please help?

For example:

If I have 3 organisms and 4 genes if the BLAST results show that Gene_1 is present in Organisms_1, and 2; Gene_2 is present in all Organisms, Gene_3 is only present in Organism_1 and Gene_4 is only present in Organism_3.

```
    Gene_1  Gene_2  Gene_3  Gene_4
Org_1   1       1       1       0       
Org_2   1       1       0       0
Org_3   0       1       0       1
```

Comment: You could try to do this using [BioPython](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc88), but it makes sense to just use `blastp` or `blastn` command line tool from the `ncbi-blast+` package (that's its name on Ubuntu)([user manual here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK1762/)).  You can see a relevant usage in the OP [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/6541/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've been using blastp from the command line, however when I looked further into this it wasn't displaying homologous genes in this fashion.

Comment: I guess I meant to say that you can wrap `blastp/n` in a `subprocess.process` and do the iterative procedure yourself in a script.  But to be of any help, I'd need a toy fasta file that will give the output describe above.  Without an example input file, you're not too likely to get much help on this site as it's more code-centric.  You may have better luck on SeqAnswers or BioStars given the current state of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right you need to get the following informations :

-which are the homologs/orthologs genes

-In wich species are they presents

There is a program that, pretty much does all this, let me present you SiLiX

http://lbbe.univ-lyon1.fr/SiLiX

You can download it and parameter it to your 95% identity, you "feed it" the result of your all against all blast. And you will get a file containing the informations you want!

The file is easily parsable (notably in python) so from it you can extract all the info you want. so from it you can create your matrix.